# Is virus protection neccesary with unprivileged users?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

If an user does not have admin privileges or privileges to edit the registry, is there any reason to have antivirus software installed?

Comment: Um...the giant, gaping, remotely-exploitable holes in Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need it.

1. In Windows XP Home, it's very hard
   to run unprivileged, so for XP the
   question is relatively moot.
2. Even if
   unprivileged, a virus can cause
   damage.  It doesn't take privileges
   to delete all user files, take
   sensitive info, make the computer a
   zombie (infecting other computers on
   your network).  If you're sysadmin,
   you'd need to clean up.
3. Privilege
   escalation: remote exploit + local
   privilege escalation => remote
   root/Administrator hole.

Comment: And don't forget Administrator account in Windows XP Home! It's a wide open hole.

Answer (score 8):

To cut a long story short: Virusses don't care about privileges =)

Comment: Just because unprivileged users can't install something doesn't mean they can't run something else.

Comment: A malicious virus could still delete everything you have rights to as that user, which is quite a bit of stuff you might not want deleted.

Answer (score 5):

While the majority of viruses get in through admin/power user accounts, there's still exploits to be had in the locked down accounts.

The general rule of thumb is "safety first", install antivirus/antimalware/anti-everythingbad software anyways.

While restricting user accounts is one way to decrease the risk, it is not a complete replacement for a good security app.

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways that a virus and/or spyware can gain access to a PC, and restricting the user's privilages is one deterrent to this but cannot be the ultimate answer unfortunately.

Are you thinking about a maintenance standpoint, or from a cost-per-machine standpoint?  If it's a cost thing, I believe that [Microsoft's Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) are free to use.

Comment: In the past, we have had issues with Symantec being a resource hog on our terminal server.

Comment: I, too, have had problems with Symantec hogging resources. Since moving away from them (and totally uninstalling anything Symantec-related), things have been fine.  How about trying the MS version for a bit and see how you get on?

Comment: I'm going to try to disable everything but the anti-virus/spyware protection in the endpoint protection suite and see if that will run correctly (atleast that is what the tech at symantec recommended)

Comment: MSE is lightweight, easy, and free.  It's the best antivirus on the market.

Comment: Is it recommended on a terminal server?

Comment: I should imagine so - after all, a Terminal Server is just a Windows Server that allows connections in from the users.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can answer your question with a question: Do you need a lock on your door if no one knows where you live?

I think "reasonable security" (in Windows) can be achieved by using a combination of anti-virus or "internet security" type software, and proper user training.

One major problem with a lot of so-called security software is that if you enable all of its features, you have no CPU cycles left for the user (this in itself, of course, may prevent anything nasty to happen to the machine :-)).

So use something like AVG Internet Security, but don't enable every single bell & whistle, and then tell the user that p0rn.net will not enhance your life ;)